# Error when using reload() in Python2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, reload

I am getting the following Error on the Python(2.7.5) Interpreter in Mac.

```
>>> reload(recommendations)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'recommendations' is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to an *existing module object* to be able to reload anything. You don't *have* a `recommendations` module there.

If `recommendations` is a module to reload, import it first:

```
import recommendations
reload(recommendations)
```

Comment: @AshwinPai your question is too thin on information to help you any further. Define 'not working', and try to tell is what problem you are trying to solve here. Do so in your question; you can edit it.